# How to create an element in the first contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

Basically I need to create a paragraph element in the first contentEditable div.

```
<div id="contentEdit" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
        <figure id="figure" contenteditable="false">
            <figcaption class="_picCaption" contentEditable="true">
                image caption
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </p>
</div>
```

What I need to do it, is when the user finish edit the caption to create a paragraph element in "contentEdit" which is the first Div.
Any ideas?

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#contentEdit", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var element = cp_getSelectionBoundaryElement(true);

    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 13) {
        if (element.tagName == "FIGCAPTION") {
            e.preventDefault();
            // get the selection range (or cursor     position)
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

            // create a p
            var newElement = document.createElement('p');
            newElement.className = '_graf_p';

            // if the range is in #contentEdit 
            if (range.startContainer.parentNode.className === '_picCaption') {
                // delete whatever is on the range
                range.deleteContents();

                // place your p
                range.insertNode(newElement);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

What is happening, I'm creating the p element inside the caption. 
I don't know how to get the range of the grandparent of figcaption.

Comment: properly write your code first

Comment: I think you may want to clean up the code formatting above if you want to get any positive responses.

Comment: Can explain more clearly about what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to use the range, you just have to wrap all the elements inside `#contentEdit` with a `p` element.

Using plain JS, you should move all the elements inside `#contentEdit` to a new `p` element, and then put it back to `#contentEdit`:

```
var content = document.getElementById('contentEdit');
var newElement = document.createElement('p');

while (content.firstChild) {
  newElement.appendChild(content.firstChild);
}

content.appendChild(newElement);
```